# A black cell is showed where I try to create a colored cell

Tags: colortbl

I'm trying to create a colored table with something like this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.5,0,0,0}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{cmyk}{0.25,0,0.25,0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{lightblue}
  Item 1 & Item 2 \\ 
  \rowcolor{lightgrey}
  $$A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$ & 
  $$B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

But in the second row the first cell is completely black! Why?.
I tried to change `smallmatrix` to `matrix` but then the cell shows a little black box. I don't understand nothing!

Comment: Don't use `$$` but single `$` for cells. `$$` is for display math and greats a paragraph. It should be anyway not be used in modern LaTeX documents, but `\[` .. `\]` instead.

Comment: I tried to do it, ...with the same result.

Comment: I think the problem comes with the `array`like environments

Comment: It wasn't meant as solution for this problem, but a general advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that the row color is reset incorrectly by the line end (`\\`) in the `smallmatrix` (`\everycr` resets the row color globally). You could use code like the following to save and restore the row color around the `smallmatrix`. This would be worth reporting to the authors of `colortbl` and `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\pagestyle{empty}
\definecolor{lightblue}{cmyk}{0.5,0,0,0}
\definecolor{lightgrey}{cmyk}{0.25,0,0.25,0}


\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mysmallmatrix}{%
    \let\saved@CT@row@color\CT@row@color
    \begin{smallmatrix}%
}{%
    \end{smallmatrix}%
    \global\let\CT@row@color\saved@CT@row@color
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{lightblue}
  Item 1 & Item 2 \\ 
  \rowcolor{lightgrey}
  $\displaystyle A=\left(\begin{mysmallmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{mysmallmatrix}\right)$ & 
  $\displaystyle B=\left(\begin{mysmallmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{mysmallmatrix}\right)$ \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you again Martin! now works fine. You save my live two times this week.

Comment: I supose I can define `mymatrix` and `myarray` environment in this way. Can I?

Comment: ...Oh, ...the same solution don't work with `matrix` environment.