# Black cell appearance in table

Tags: tables

I use this simple code:-

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{?}{!{\vrule width 3pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[t]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{|p{30mm}| p{35mm} | p{20mm}|}
\rowcolor{gray!100}
\hline
iota    &   iota     &   iota  \\
\rowcolor{gray!40}
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}


\begin{table}[]
\centering
\arrayrulecolor{black}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|}
\cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & t & r & e \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{1} & l & l & l \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{2} & l & l & l \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

It gives a black cell. I looked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22859/a-black-cell-is-showed-where-i-try-to-create-a-colored-cell) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297335/table-cell-with-unwanted-black-background) but unable to figure my solution.

I tried using this line instead above: -

```
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}t & r & e \\ \hline
```

But this is not visually appealing as the cell borders appear thinner than others. Can someone suggest a good solution?

Comment: Please, make a *complete* example. The snippet only creates 44 cells (11 rows, 4 columns) with *white* background and 43 cells are surrounded by the black vertical and horizontal lines.

Comment: please provide a document that can be tested not just a fragment. I guess (but you do not say) that you are using `\usepackage[table][xcolor}` to define these commands?

Comment: `\arrayrulecolor{black}` is the default so you don't have to write it, unless it has been changed previously. I don't understand the line you changed to: of course you'll obtain a black cell since you ask it. What do you think `cellcolor[HTML]{FFFFFF}` means?

Comment: One second, i  will add the full code!

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Added full code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have added the package now.

Comment: @Bernard I updated my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last `\rowcolor{gray!40}` in the first `tabular`, where a row for this command is missing in this table.

From the documentation of `\rowcolor` in package `colortbl` (loaded by option `table` of package `xcolor`):

> `\rowcolor` [...]. It must be used at the start of a row.